# My program has a memory leak

Tags: iphone, ios4, memory, memory-leaks, memory-management

```
-(IBAction)play2;

{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, 
                                             (CFStringRef) @"Bear3", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);

    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

This is giving me an error:

```
potential leak of an object allocated " CFBundleResourceURL
returns a Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count
```

Answer (score 2):

[AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID)(soundFileURLRef, &soundID); - leak here, because create added to retain count

use [AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID) after playing sound

Answer (score 2):

`CFBundleCopyResourceURL` contains copy so your retain count on `soundFileURLRef` is in fact 1. When you are done with it call `CFRelease(soundFileURLRef)` to decrement your retain count.

In addition to the error you're getting, SAKrisT's answer about calling `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID` on the object you created with `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` is also something to address.

Comment: Avoid discussing the actual retain count of an object (which is strictly an implementation detail) and instead think about objects in term of ownership.

Comment: @dreamlax I was discussing the retain count because it's mentioned in the error that the question is about.

Comment: read the error more carefully, it does not tell you the *actual* retain count, just the *relative* retain count in terms of your ownership.

Answer (score 2):

`CFBundleCopyResourceURL` creates a `CFURLRef` object *that you own*, so you need to relinquish ownership of this object at some point with `CFRelease`. Similarly you will need to balance your call to `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` with another call to `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID`.

For Core Foundation, functions that have the word `Create` or `Copy` in their name return an object that you own, so you must relinquish ownership of it when you are done with it. For more information about Core Foundation memory management, see the [Core Foundation Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html).

Just to give you a hint, I would probably handle the memory management like this (although I haven't coded Objective-C for a while). This also assumes you want to keep the URL reference for whatever reason:

```
@interface MyClass
{
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    UInt32 soundID;
}

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, CFSTR("Bear3"), CFSTR("wav"));

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
    CFRelease(soundFileURLRef);
    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction) play2
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Comment: after i release that the sound will not play anymore

Comment: Release it *when you no longer need it*, i.e. when your class is deallocating.

Comment: Make both the `soundFileURLRef` and `soundID` into instance variables, then in your object's `dealloc` method, put `CFRelease(soundFileURLRef); AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);`. (It may not be necessary to make the URL object an instance variable)

Comment: how would those instance variables be am new to coding so i don't know much

Comment: @alfred: I have edited my answer, hopefully this clarifies a few things.

Comment: will that code work to make a soundboard app do i just copy that code for each sound

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using ARC (available in xcode 4.2) then you need to release anything you alloc. add `[alert release]` after `[alert show]`.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you use the keyword 'alloc' , it means you are allocating some memory space for your object. Now if you don't release it yourself or autorelease it, then it shows 'memory leak'. It is not only about uialertview, but for every other objects also. 
 You may want to release the alertview object in dealloc() method, but still it will show memory leak as the memory is unused for a long time. 
 So , first you show the alert by [alert show], then you need the object anymore, so release it by [alert release]; 
 Enjoy !! :)

Comment: -1: He can't release in dealloc as the scope is inside the pushAbout function. It's not that it shows memory leak - it is a memory leak - and it would not show as a leak if it was unused for a long time but eventually released. Reread the memory management guide.