# Memory leak in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios4, memory, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My program has a memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055327/my-program-has-a-memory-leak)

```
-(IBAction)pushAbout  
{  
    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"About" message:@"Created by Alfred"   delegate:nil      
cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

it is telling me there is potential leak of an object allocated